# How do I increase the fixed width font size in Sphinx / reStructured Text?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm using Sphinx to generate documentation which uses reStructured Text as it's markup.  However, when I use some inline formatting to make text show up in a fixed width font `--no-cache` the rendered HTML shows the text in a smaller font.

How do I increase the fixed-width font size in Sphinx / reStructured Text so it matches the normal text font-size?

**Answer**

With Chris's help I was able to override the default font style in the CSS to increase the fixed-width font size:

1. Edit `conf.py` to specify html theme and css file:

   html_theme = 'default'
   html_style = 'overrides.css'
2. Next, I created a new css file `static/overrides.css` with the following contents:

   @import url("default.css");

   tt {
   font-size: 130%;
   }

I selected to use `130%` because `default.css` defines this:

```
div.body p, div.body dd, div.body li {
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 130%;
}
```

And now I get fixed width text matching the regular text in the generated html.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can edit the CSS stylesheet for whichever theme you are using. For example, for the default theme, you can edit the [default.css_t file](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/src/0e789eafb3bb89c0740321dd9271ca6fcaa5abee/sphinx/themes/default/static/default.css_t?at=default). Specifically you can specify an increased `font-size` (for example, use `font-size: 1.1em` or similar) in the [`pre` rule on line 274](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/src/0e789eafb3bb89c0740321dd9271ca6fcaa5abee/sphinx/themes/default/static/default.css_t?at=default#cl-274).

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'm closer to getting what I want.  Is there a way to inherit the default css and just override some of the rules?

Comment: No problem. See the configuration file option [`html_style`](http://sphinx-doc.org/config.html#confval-html_style).

Comment: I should have mentioned its the inline-style, code blocks I'm okay with.  Following your suggestions I was successful.  I'll update my questions with the complete answer and mark this as accepted.  Thanks!