# Is it possible to have separate new lines for method definition sphinx docs

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Is it possible to have separate 
new lines for method definition 
input arguments sphinx docs
for example:

[image]

So it would look like:

```
lib.dashboards.post_all_dashboards(   # black line
         dashboards_location,         # blue line
         values,                      # ...
         values,                      # ...
         user,
         ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with custom CSS inserted into your theme's style sheet or by overriding it with the following:

```
dt em:nth-child(n+2)::before {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
}
```

It gets close to what you want, but it does not indent the args.

See this post for [how to customize a theme's CSS file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24380767/2214933).

Comment: could you please navigate me where exactly I will find this css file ? Is it a part of the documentation which has been generated by `make html` ? thx