# How to increase the font size for code samples in sphinx?

Tags: css, python-sphinx

When i want to display some with fixed-width font in Sphinx, i place it between two inverted ticks ("inline markup for code samples"):

```
The class ``Test1`` is pure virtual.
```

Unfortunately, the size of this font is much smaller than the font for normal text:

[image: The html output of the inline code sample]

Searching for a method to increase this font i found the post

[How do I increase the fixed width font size in Sphinx / reStructured Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24335079/how-do-i-increase-the-fixed-width-font-size-in-sphinx-restructured-text) ,

but i think it is out of date (2014), because the solutions given there seem not to work - for instance, the file `default.css_t` does not exist in my installation.

I also tried to modify `/build/html/_static/basic.css`, but after doing  `build html` my changes have vanished and everything looked like it did before.

How can i change the font size of code samples in the current version of sphinx (4.4.0)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use custom CSS on a default sphinx theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57415129/how-to-use-custom-css-on-a-default-sphinx-theme)

Comment: @LexLi Yes thank you! by changing the font-size in the code element of my custom css i now have the desired size for the code samples.